# API to get Windows Azure Virtual Machines sizes

Tags: azure, size, virtual-machine

I have the following table: http://windowsazureguide.net/tag/auzre-virtual-machines-sizes-bandwidth/
But I am interested to exract these vales using some API (since they can change)
So how can I retrieve the data about Azure VM size?
I suppose it is could be done from RoleInstance Class. Can you point me how?

Answer (score 0):

The [List Role Sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469422.aspx) operation in the Azure Service Management REST API provides the closest you can get to this information. There may be an equivalent method in the .NET API.